# Writing a parser in C++ to parse the given HTML entities

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, parsing

Recently, I faced a coding question in which we had to **parse the mention HTML entities**. These following entities needed to be parsed -

- `&quot;` to **"**
- `&apos;` to - **'**
- `&gt;` to **>**
- `&lt;` to **<**
- `&amp;` to **&**
- `&frasl;` to **⁄**

There will be a string `txt` given which has to be parsed as per above rules. Following is my approach which works fine.

```
string parse(string txt){
    int n=txt.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){             //edit : why don't I get an error even though I loop for full length after erasing some elements of string?
            if(txt[i]=='&'){
                if(i+5<n&&txt.substr(i,6)=="&quot;"){
                    txt[i]='"';
                    txt.erase(i+1,5);
                }
                else if(i+5<n&&txt.substr(i,6)=="&apos;"){
                    txt[i]=(char)(39);            //I also wasn't able to do like this -txt[i]='\''; would be nice if someone tells why this gave error
                    txt.erase(i+1,5);
                }
                else if(i+4<n&&txt.substr(i,5)=="&amp;"){
                    txt[i]='&';
                    txt.erase(i+1,4);
                }
                else if(i+3<n&&txt.substr(i,4)=="&gt;"){
                    txt[i]='>';
                    txt.erase(i+1,3);
                }
                else if(i+3<n&&txt.substr(i,4)=="&lt;"){
                    txt[i]='<';
                    txt.erase(i+1,3);
                }
                else if(i+6<n&&txt.substr(i,7)=="&frasl;"){
                    txt[i]='/';
                    txt.erase(i+1,6);
                }       
            }
        }
    return txt;
}
```

I feel I did it in the most brute way possible. But I wonder if there is another approach which is **simpler(probably, shorter)** than my code.

**Any help or approach is appreciated !**

**EDIT** : As brought to my notice by a comment, my looping actually uses the originally string length `n` but I am erasing some elements when looping reducing the `txt` string length. Suprisingly, I don't get any error and it would be helpful if someone explains why?

Comment: Collect all characters between '&' and ';' first, then look up all collected characters in a fixed lookup map, replace it. About a quarter of the code, in my estimation. The End.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried using the `replace()` in my code but that was giving me segmentation fault...but with proper implementation that could probably work. But I was wondering if there is a way/built-in method which replaces all occurences of given substrings(HTML entity in our case) that we pass to it?

Comment: When I wrote "replace it" I don't necessarily mean actually using `replace()`. There is nothing in the C++ library that will do this kind of replacement. The whole purpose of this task is demonstrated your ability to implement a new algorithm by yourself, instead of relying on an existing one in the C++ library.

Comment: Are you sure that the above code works correctly? You have `n  = txt.size()`, but do you adjust `n` when erasing? Seems like any erasure in your code results in out of bounds access.

Comment: @paler123 Good notice ! Actually that doesn't give any error. I don't know how but the function works and now I really wonder how?

Comment: *"Suprisingly, I don't get any error"* -- undefined behavior is not required to give an error. (If you want an error, try using `txt.at(i)` instead of `txt[i]`.)

Comment: *"it would be helpful if someone explains why"* - Why? Because this is C++. A C++ compiler accepts any code that it cannot prove to be incorrect. And it's not trying very hard to prove anything. There is a whole family of tools that try to make up for that, like AddressSanitizer, UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer, lifetime checkers, and so on. If you're writing C++, you need to use them, always, liberally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would suggest approaching this problem:

0) firstly I would just create a new string with the correctly formatted output. This is easier than having to modify the string in-place - you just build the string up bit by bit. Plus I don't know if modifying it in-place is beneficial anyway, every time you erase some characters I imagine elements are being copied along the elements along to keep the memory together (contiguous).

1) use std::string::find to find the next occurrence of each character
2) of the strings that you are looking for, pick the one that occurs next (smallest string::find value)
3) append the characters up to this point to the output string
4) append the replacement text instead of the original text
5) repeat - std::string::find has an optional pos argument indicating where to start the search
6) loop ends when all find results are == std::string::npos

There are probably many ways to solve this, and probably something using regexes would be more elegant, but this is how I would do it.

As an aside, relating to your edit, there might not be any errors if you are running without debugging. I think if you have an access violation the console app will just exit without any related output of you're not attached to a debugger. This is why it is good idea to run stuff in a debug environment if you can.

EDIT: Using std::string::replace is another function that you could use here

Comment: Yea, your method of building another string altogether surely makes more sense and does work. Although I was wondering if there's more elegant way. Like in python, I could do it easily using `split()` and `join()`. You also mentioned about using regex. If you know about that, can you add it to the answer?

Comment: Edited my answer to mention std::string::replace - this might make the code a bit more concise. That said string manipulation is often a bit messy in C++ - I often turn to boost to see if there is already a function that is at least closer to what I want to do. I'm afraid I've not used regexes much, but I'm sure there will be some good introductory articles on the web.

Comment: ok, I will be sure to look on the web. Anyways, Thanks for your answer !

Comment: No problem! Good luck in your future coding endeavours :)